# jquery - e refer as Event

Tags: jquery

In my jquery snippet, am using the function(e) and also in some places i used function(event)

How system really understand the e is the event object,

is any where they declared by default ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you *call* [the event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) (as long as it's not a keyword), it's whatever the first parameter is, you're just giving it an identifier.

For example, you could call it `wakyThing` and it'd still work...it's *still* the first argument passed to the handler.  This is the same for all jQuery handlers, [from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

> The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler.